# Java Eclipse Regex Multiline Search

Tags: java, regex, eclipse, swing, replace

We recently converted a large project from Swing to JavaFX.  A conversion program was written to automate some of this process which saved a lot of time, but also left us with some issues.  One of which is we have some Alerts that never have `showAndWait()` called.  I was hoping to put a Regex together to find all instances in our project that meet the following criteria:

Starts with **new Alert(**

End with **");**

And potentially contains 0 or multiple line feeds along with any characters in between the parenthesis.

I was able to come up with this: `new Alert\(*.*\R*.*\"\)\;`

But it seems to also include results that end with the `showAndWait()` call as well.

Examples:

`new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION, "This alert should not be matched").showAndWait();`

`new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION, "This alert should be matched");`

Thanks

Comment: can you provide an example of a wrongly-matched Alert?

Comment: Added to the question.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a *tempered greedy token* solution:

```
\bnew\s+Alert\((?:(?!\.showAndWait\(\);\s*$)[\s\S])*"\);
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ypRLz6/1) and a screenshot below:

[image]

**Pattern details**:

- `\bnew` - a whole word `new`
- `\s+` -  1 or more whitespaces
- `Alert\(`  -  a sequence of literal chars `Alert(`
- `(?:(?!\.showAndWait\(\);\s*$)[\s\S])*` - the tempered greedy token matching any char (`[\s\S]`) that is not the starting char of a `.showAndWait();` + zero or more whitespaces+end of line sequence
- `"\);`   -  a sequence of literal chars `");`

Comment: To understand what a [*tempered greedy token*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970) is see my other answer.